# A problem in the Hecke's trick method

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, modular-forms, absolute-convergence

In his 'Introduction to modular forms', Don Zagier deals with the Hecke's trick which I don't really understand :

Let 
$$G_2(\tau)=-\frac{1}{24}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\sigma_1(n)q^n}$$
and
$$G_2^*(\tau)=\frac{-1}{8\pi^2}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}{\left(\sum_{m,n}{'}{\frac{1}{(m\tau+n)^2 |m\tau+n|^{\epsilon}}}\right)}$$
It is said that with Poisson formula, one can find that $G_2^*(\tau)=G_2(\tau)+(8\pi v)^{-1}$ where $\tau=u+i v \in \left\{\Im(\tau)>0\right\}$.

Can someone develop the proof or give a reference ?

Thanks a lot !